# iptables block outgoing on port, allow selected IP's

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, smtp

Debian 7

iptables v1.4.14 (there are no rules)

Need to block all outgoing connections on ports 25,587,465 and allow only on specific IP's.

What I've tried:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 25,587,465 -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.1.1 --match multiport --dports 25,587,465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s **.**.**.*** --match multiport --dports 25,587,465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s **.**.**.*** --match multiport --dports 25,587,465 -j ACCEPT
```

I tried different order for rules, but it's not working as expected.

Comment: It does not really help to say that it's not working as expected. We don't know what you expected and what behavior you are seeing. Edit your question to include that information, and maybe you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The iptables rules are evaluated in order, that means that if you block everything in the first rule, there is no point to allow something later, those rules will never be reached.

I'm quite sure you don't want to match the source address, you want the destination.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.1.1 --match multiport --dports 25,587,465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d **.**.**.*** --match multiport --dports 25,587,465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d **.**.**.*** --match multiport --dports 25,587,465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 25,587,465 -j REJECT
```